# C++ begin() and end()

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am reading the `C++ Primer 5th Edition` book. Now and then, the author uses the functions `begin` and `end`.

For example:

```
int ia[3][4] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

int (*p)[4] = begin(ia);
```

However, I get the error:

```
error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
```

I am running gcc 4.9.2, and I use the following command to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The author probably has a declaration like `using namespace std;` or `using std::begin;`. You need to type `std::begin` without one of those. You might also need to `#include<iterator>`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap it in the `std` scope, the function is [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)

```
int (*p)[3] = std::begin(ia);
```

Likely in the text, the author had a `using` directive at the top of the code.

```
using namespace std;
```

I would [discourage you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) from using the latter method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include header `<iterator>` where function `begin` is declared

```
#include <iterator>
```

and if you did not include the using directive

```
using namespace std;
```

then you have to use a qualified name for `begin`

```
int ( *p )[4] = std::begin( ia );
```

or

```
auto p = std::begin( ia );
```

In fact statement

```
int ( *p )[4] = std::begin( ia );
```

is equivalent to

```
int ( *p )[4] = ia;
```

and expression `std::end( ia )` is equivalent to `ia + 3`